# OpsHub TFS to VSOnline Migration Utility - Will WorkItem # not stay the same?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

We're migrating various projects from on-prem to VS Online using the OpsHub Migration Tool.

I'm seeing that the work item numbers on-premises does not match the same work items number in VSO. Is that by design, or am I using the tool wrong?

If not, is there a way to retain the work item numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workitem # is auto-generated field in VS Online, OpsHub Migration Tool do not migrate them. OpsHub starts migration of workitems across workitem types(Bug, Test Case, etc) in parallel. Thus there is no guarantee that workitem# will be same in both end point.

Comment: We have other systems that references the Work Items by #, so we need to get them updated with the new number.

How can I get at the list of the original WorkItem number and the newly VSO allocated WorkItem # from the OpsHub Migration Utility?

Comment: We still have the virtual machine that was used to run the OpsHub utility so we should still have all the data and logs from the migration available to query. Please let us know how we can get at the cross reference, or even how we might develop a utility ourselves to extract the list of work item numbers from your data.

Comment: Nevermind, I'll get it myself. I see you are using HSQLDB for the Migration Tool. For other who are interested, you can easily get to the database and   you'll mainly be interested in the `OPSHUB.OHMT_EAI_ENTITY_INFO` table. Join the table to itself on the GLOBAL_ID field where the first table's (call it source) ENTITY_INFO_ID is less than (<) the second table's (call it destination).  Use at your own risk / peril as I'm not responsible for anything you do.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. Work item numbers are not unique per project, but are set at the project collection level. The only way to import them while retaining values would be to import to a completely empty account, that would only work for the first project being imported though, since, after importing the first project, any further project would have to be re-numbered.

On an on-premise TFS, under very special circumstances and with high enough permissions on a completely bare collection it's possible to import a project while retaining Id's.

In the cloud, it's just not supported.